# Handling subdomains with nuxtJS

Tags: routes, subdomain, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm having a site, let's say `example.com` which shares the layout and few components with subdomain `blog.example.com` so i want to create common nuxtJS project for this so that the routes and all things will be optimized by nuxtJS, i don't want to create 2 projects for this as there would be repetition of components, how can i achieve this result?

Comment: The way you are planning to host is important here. Are you planning on using something like Netlify for static-site generation or something like Heroku for server-side-rendering?

Comment: actually I'm hosting on vercel with **server-side rendering** and I've already configured my domain for wild cards so whatever be the subdomain, it is going to load my site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved the result by filtering the routes to remove and then removing the folder name the path and route name, with `@nuxtjs/router` module, and for simplicity I've created my own module to do the exact same with user friendly interface, have a look at [k-domains](https://www.npmjs.com/package/k-domains) npm module.
Here's the link to the [article](https://blog.madhusudan.live/blog/handling-multiple-sub-domains-with-nuxtjs-and-k-domains)[image: handle multiple subdomains in nuxtJS project]

Comment: is this lib solve wildcard  *.abc.com domains?

Comment: please  update your  answar with wildcard.